# Setting ImageView Image results in error

Tags: java, image, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to set the `Image` of an `ImageView` object. My code:

```
Image photo = new Image("http://example.com/image.jpg", 100, 0, false, false);
ImageView face = new ImageView();
face.setImage(photo);
```

I'm getting errors on lines 2 and 3, but I'm following [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) pretty closely.
Excerpt from documentation:

```
// load the image
Image image = new Image("flower.png");

// simple displays ImageView the image as is
ImageView iv1 = new ImageView();
iv1.setImage(image);
```

---

**Errors**

Line 2:

```
java: constructor ImageView in class javax.swing.text.html.ImageView cannot be applied to given types;
  required: javax.swing.text.Element
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Line 3:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setImage(javafx.scene.image.Image)
  location: variable face of type javax.swing.text.html.ImageView
```

Comment: Can you add the error to your question ?

Comment: Compile error or runtime error? If it's a compile error, please include your imports.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the wrong imports. You need

```
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView ;
```

You have imported `javax.swing.text.html.ImageView`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot, I had the same problem =)